# "Extra }" error when inserting quote mark " after string in tikz \overlay \node enviroment

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, tikz-node, syntax-highlighting

thanks in advance for your precious help.
I am trying to highlight non seriffed text commands inside a grey box `="easy here"`. Something like this:

[image]

To get that in Latex, the following code is enough for the purpose (non serif out of the mwe):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[draw=gray!10, fill=gray!10, inner sep=1.5pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=0.5mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}
\newcommand\es[1]{\textsf{\mybox[]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\mybox{"noProb}\\
\mybox{Still fine: =IF(1<2,"Yes","No")}\\
\mybox{="whyItDoesNotLikeThis:"}\\
\end{document}
```

However, quotes marks after text produce and odd "extra }" error:

```
linha 10: Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. \mybox{="whyItDoesNotLikeThis:"}
linha 10: Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete. \mybox{="whyItDoesNotLikeThis:"}
linha 8: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

[image]

PS: Need to use `mdframed` for other purpose in the real doc, however, even if only use `tikz` package, the problem remains. Perhaps there is a proper way to this stuf, as this syntax is more than common all over the internet.

Any hint more than welcome. Have a nice day.

Comment: Note that I would probably move to `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed`. The main issue here is Portuguese babel which makes `"` into an active char. What exactly does `"..."` mean in your output?

Comment: HI @daleif, thanks for your comment. What do you mean with with `"..."` in output?

Comment: What exactly does `="whyItDoesNotLikeThis:"` represent?

Comment: This represents how to enter text in an Excel formula. ="string". I want to highlight whenever mention to commands with the grey box around it, pretty much as we do `here` in stackexchange

Comment: Understood. Is this text in English or Portuguese? I'm quite sire the problem goes away of the `babel` language is `english`

Comment: This a tutorial written in Portuguese. The code example to highlight `="Texto introduzido numa fórmula"`

Comment: If you don't use the `"` shorthand in your text, then you can add `\shorthandoff{"}` to the start of the document to disable the active `"`

Comment: It does the trick. Thanks